# Is it common for a U.S. president to have official documents in their personal posession after they leave office?

Tags: united-states, president

The Florida home of a former U.S. president was recently raided because he was believed to have several documents that belong to the government in his home. Fifteen boxes of such papers were recovered from the home. The way I've heard the investigation described, the F.B.I. carried out the raid because it was believed there were top secret documents that needed to be recovered among the papers in the Florida home. The unspoken message I seem to hear in reporting on the issue is that the problem isn't that he had official documents in his possession, but that he had top secret documents in his possession. This makes me wonder: is it common for people to have official government documents in their possession after they leave the office of the president?

EDIT: I left the original question. Response to the comment asking about if this question is focused on top secret documents: not exclusively. I wrote this question with the idea of responding to someone hypothetically asking, "what's the big deal? They all take home the papers from their office when they leave". I had a feeling the president was lawfully required to leave all the documents his office created and couldn't take them after the term is over. Official documents is clearly more than just top secret documents.

To address the other comment asking for clarification: I didn't mean sundry items, like a get well letter on presidential letterhead. I meant more substantive documents, like documents from the office of the president that affect national policies or regulations or are official communications with domestic or foreign officials but since I don't work for the White House and don't study any branch of U.S. government closely, I don't know all the aspects of documents created in that office. I searched a little about N[ational Archives ("N.A.") and presidential record](https://search.brave.com/search?q=what%20does%20national%20archives%20keep%20from%20president)s. So if it clarifies some: "Presidential records" as defined by the N.A [here](https://www.archives.gov/about/laws/presidential-records.html) seems to describe what I'm asking about.

To kind of answer my question, I came across this article from [factcheck](https://www.factcheck.org/2022/02/former-presidents-are-not-allowed-to-take-home-official-records/) in my search: the president is not allowed take home records. I feel silly answering my own question, so if someone else wants to write a thorough answer, the factcheck link and the link I included from the N.A., should provide some material for an answer.

I've spent a lot of time working on this edit. Apologies if it didn't improve the question.

Comment: It would be nice, if people give examples of this happening in the past, that they indicate whether this possession was officially sanctioned or not (say by the National Archives).  Also, classification levels, *confidential, top secret*, would bear mentioning as well.  Note that some level of *access, if not possession*, to official info is expected , at least for some positions, not necessarily POTUS.  [CIA directors get this:] (https://www.politico.com/story/2018/08/15/trump-pulls-security-clearance-of-ex-cia-director-brennan-778791)

Comment: I don't think this can be answered quite as it's written.  It really depends on what you mean by "official government documents" - that phrase can include everything from a letter on Presidential letterhead, to a copy of the Congressional Record, to Top Secret SCI reports.

Comment: If you're talking about classified information, then this is a duplicate of https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/12102/do-previous-presidents-elected-officials-retain-security-clearance-after-they-le

Comment: You are mistaken about the type of documents. The highly classified documents are a much bigger problem, but any official Government documents are the property of the Government and it is improper to keep them after you leave the job.

Comment: It's [perfectly valid](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) to self-answer a question, especially if you discovered the answer through more research after asking it. Share what you've learned!

Comment: @JohnFx "...it is improper to keep them after you leave the job" That would mean that already the existence of the 15 boxes of government documents found in Trump's private location is illegal.

Comment: @Trilarion - I said improper, not illegal, but it is probably both if he didn't have authorization from NARA

Comment: @Bobson Receiving classified briefings is not the same as maintaining personal custody of classified documents, so that's not a duplicate even if OP here is talking about classified info.

Comment: @TylerH - True.  Just because someone may have TS clearance doesn't mean they can take TS documents home with them.  It's still related, though, although definitely not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it common for people to have official government documents in their
> possession after they leave the office of the president?

No. Not in the modern era. In modern times, when the matter was legally regulated, this has been a standard task list item for the transition team of the departing President.

Before this matter (e.g. confidentiality regulation) was formally regulated legally, most Presidents contributed documents to a Presidential library, sometimes with a "do not release" before date.

Comment: "the matter was legally regulated" I think the loophole here might be that the former president could argue that he declassified the documents before keeping them (as Trump tried to say). Would this change things?

Comment: @Trilarion One issue with that is did the-then president follow the proper procedure? Another issue is, was he capable of declassifying this document? Because the president is not capable of declassifying certain material (e.g. 'nuclear secrets).

Comment: @Trilarion none of the laws cited in the search warrant depends on whether the documents were classified.  Presidential records are the property of the US government regardless, and the espionage act covers documents that "could be used to the injury of the United States" without regard to classification.

Comment: @Lag even if the documents _were_ declassified (and I agree with you that they probably weren't), they remain the property of the US government and they remain subject to the Espionage Act.  The sections of the criminal code cited in the search warrant are 18 USC 793, 2071, and 1519.  The first is the espionage act, the second covers mishandling of federal records, and the third is obstruction of justice.

Comment: @Trilarion The U.S. did not always have laws regarding document management and secrecy classifications. Before there were laws on the topic, document management was ad hoc and governed by custom rather than law. Other comments address the declassification issue, but I have focused on pre-Trump Presidential practice.

Comment: @ohwilleke since when does the US then has these laws approximately? I guess that at the very least they pre-date Trump?

Comment: Some are post-WWI (the Espionage Act, e.g.), and many are post-WWII. All pre-date Trump, but the point is that when you are looking at what past Presidents did (as the OP did), pre-WWI Presidencies and even pre-WWII Presidencies, have limited relevant. There is a very small sample size of relevant Presidents even out of the total of 46 of them.

Comment: @Trilarion the Presidential Records Act was passed in 1978. https://www.archives.gov/presidential-libraries/laws/1978-act.html  So the laws predate the situation I asked about by decades.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is confusing because there are actually several different issues here, as I mention in [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/74812/18471). These include:

1. **Records produced by the Trump administration.** Individual documents from this set may or may not be classified (I expect most are not), but under the [Presidential Records Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presidential_Records_Act) these belong to the United States, not the ex-president, and the government is obligated to preserve them. My understanding is that attempts specifically to gain possession of these (which have been occurring since around the start of the year) have all been requests for Trump and/or his retainers to voluntarily hand them over.
2. **Sensitive documents that are being handled improperly or exposed to unauthorized people,** such as by being stored with insufficient security or in a place where people without appropriate clearances can access them. This includes, but may not be limited to, documents containing [classified information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classified_information_in_the_United_States), defense information, and so on.

This second category could involve prosecutable crimes under, e.g. [18 U.S. Code § 798](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/798) (Disclosure of classified information) or [18 U.S. Code § 793](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/793) (Gathering, transmitting or losing defense information); the second of these was mentioned in the [search warrant](https://www.documentcloud.org/documents/22131378-trump-search-warrant).

Also mentioned in the search warrant were [§ 2071](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2071) (Concealment, removal, or mutilation generally) and [§ 1519](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1519) (Destruction, alteration, or falsification of records in Federal investigations and bankruptcy), which could conceivably cover documents in neither category above.

Note that this does not mean that anybody *will* be prosecuted, or even that the Justice department is attempting to prosecute anybody. It's possible, for example, that they created and executed the search warrant simply because they wanted to get some sensitive documents back under government control and were having trouble doing so via less forceful means, and they'll be happy to let the matter drop now that they've done that.

Also note that, as I mention [in this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/74818/18471), Trump had the ability to unilaterally declassify certain types of documents while he was president, and could do so without telling anyone. If these were not reclassified before the government took back possession of them there would seem to be nothing to prosecute, at least under § 798, for those documents, though the government wouldn't know this until Trump got around to telling them that he'd done so.

Comment: "*and could do so without telling anyone*" No, the bar is low for a President to declassify something, but they _do_ actually have to _tell someone_. If the POTUS doesn't tell anyone they want some info declassified, then it is not declassified, because there's no one around to make the changes in relevant apparatuses or mark documents as declassified. At least until humans develop the ability to read minds or communicate telepathically in some way. *Ex post facto* declassification is not a thing. And for anyone wondering, *former* Presidents don't have the authority to declassify anything.

Comment: @TylerH Some people think POTUS has to tell someone; others don't. It doesn't appear to have been conclusively determined either way, but keep in mind that ultimate authority on who can declassify things and how rests with POTUS. See [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/74818/18471) for more details.

Comment: And yes, I agree that _ex post facto_ declassification is not a thing, which is why I never suggested that it could happen, nor suggested that he declassified anything after he left office. However, he could have "secretly" declassified something while in office, telling nobody at the time, and only later (after leaving office) informing people that he'd done that. If he claims to have done that, there's no way to prove that he didn't.

Comment: Still no; there is no "secret declassification". If POTUS wants to declassify something, they usually can. But they have to _tell someone_. It is not logically justifiable to claim whatever you want to share is declassified because you decided so in your head and just forgot to tell anyone. There are extensive review processes by numerous offices when data is declassified, because it often has real impact on other people (which is the point of classifying information: all the people that can be affected by it). It's not just a game of "I'm the POTUS so I get to know stuff you don't know".

Comment: If you're looking for some kind of explicit entry in the rule book that handles this neatly, you're not going to find it spelled out, because no President has ever been thick enough to contend this point. Trump, however, made doing dumb stuff to test the rules of the system his signature move, so it's perhaps not surprising that he's still finding ways, a year and a half after leaving office, to do it.

Comment: @TylerH You are correct (at least in my opinion) that "It is not logically justifiable to claim whatever you want to share is declassified because you decided so in your head and just forgot to tell anyone." Your mistake is in your assumption that if something is not logically justifable it cannot be done.

Comment: It's not about whether it can be _attempted_ by someone (e.g. Trump), but rather about what the Judiciary will accept. Luckily, federal judges are (for the most part) saner than Trump, and more interested in the rule of law. In any action at the federal gov't level, you have checks and balances. Even with the supreme cosmic power of declassification, POTUS' actions are still subject to review by the Legislative and/or Judicial branches, depending on the action.

Comment: @TylerH Exactly. Since no judge has ruled on this, we don't know that the system as it stands does or does not allow something you think is logically unjustifiable. Also, it's my impression that U.S. judges tend to be more adverse to ruling against the executive when ruling on things covered by executive orders than they are when ruling on things covered by statute law.